# Proper Practice when checking a List in a Constructor

Tags: java, exception, methods, constructor

I have the following `Book` class (I've omitted the irrelevant code).

```
public final class Book {

    public Book(String bookTitle, List<Author> listofAuthors, int numberofchapters, String ISBN) 
    { 
      //Ommitted other variable initializations. 
      this.checkAuthors(listofAuthors);
      this.listofAuthors = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<Author>(listofAuthors));          
    }

    private void checkAuthors(List<Author> checkifEmpty)
    {   
       if(checkifEmpty == null){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException( "List of authors is null");
       }

       if (checkifEmpty.size() == 0){
          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "The authors list contains no authors");
       }

       for (Author checkEmpty : checkifEmpty){
          if(checkEmpty == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("A book must have at least one author");
        }
    }

}
```

I included a private method to check the `List` of authors to make sure that the `List` collection isn't 0, and to prevent

```
Author bookAuthor = null;

List<Author> listofAuthors = new ArrayList<Author>();
listofAuthors.add(bookAuthor);
```

or

```
List<Author> listofAuthors = null;
Book tlac = new Book("book title goes here", listofAuthors, 30, "isbn goes here");
```

from happening.

**Questions:**

1. Is calling a `private` method from the `constructor` and doing the work there considered a bad practice? If so, how should I correct it?
2. In the `private` method `checkAuthors` I use the [`==` instead of `equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java). My intention is to check that no object stored in the `List<Author>` has a value of `null`. Is this case, I found using `==` works, if I were to use `equals()` it give me `null` as the error message. Is using `==` correct in this case, if not, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is calling a private method from the constructor and doing the work it's doing considered bad practice? If so, how should I correct it?

No, go for it as long as it makes sense, i.e. reduces the complexity of a single method or [DRYs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) up the code.

> In the private method checkAuthors I use the == instead of equals(). My intention is to check that no object stored in the List has a value of null. Is this case, I found using == works, if I were to use equals() it give me null as the error message. Is using == correct in this case, if not, what should I be doing?

Depends how specialised your object has to be. If this is crucial state-checking that is used in multiple places in your application then failing fast on construction is a good idea. Consider using something like Guava's [preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) to save yourself some typing.